# Redirect URI exactly the same yet error occurring

Tags: java, android, redirect, oauth-2.0, postman

I am working on adding oAuth2 authorization flow to my app.

I have got to the stage where I am exchanging the authentication code for an access token.

The API I am working with is from Kiteworks and I have followed their documentation as to what is needed in the request. I have used Postman to test the request and I am receiving this error every time:

```
{
"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
"error_description": "The redirect URI is missing or do not match",
"error_uri": "http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3"}
```

I have double and triple checked that the redirect Uri in my request is exactly the same to the one I was given during set-up, no different caps or spaces and https is used for both.

What else can I do to get past this?

Thanks

Comment: May be you are not sending the token request with correct format. Are you using x-www-form-urlencoded to send the contents of token request ?

Comment: Hi @KavinduDodanduwa Yeah I have tried both JSON and x-www-form-urlencoded. JSON was responding with "grant_type" has not been set even though I had it in correctly. Then when I switched to using the x-www then the above error is what I was receiving in postman.